# ASP.NET Dynamic script file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am very new to ASP.NET.

I have a javascript file where I would like to dynamically enter values when the page loads. To test this out I tried:

```
$
(
    function () 
    {

        alert('<% = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy") %>');
    }
)
```

The alert fires on page load as expected but the VB is not executing; I just get VB code echoed back as if it were just another string.

The script file is declared on the site master page right before the closing body tag.

What an I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What `vb` code? btw. If You want to execute that `js` code from Your question, then, just before closing `body`, well before `form`, tag put `<script type="text/javascript">alert('<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy") %>');</script>`, without `function()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code between the `<%` and `%>` tags is server side script. The file it contains should be parsed by the server, so the code can be executed. In Asp.Net, for example the .aspx files, or in MVC the .cshtml files or .vbhtml files will be parsed by the server and the code on them executed, before the page is sent to the client.

Your javascript file is not parsed by the server, and the server side code is not executed before it's sent to the client. So what the browser, and the javascript engine sees, is literally what you typed, so that's what you see in the alert.

If you want serverside code to be executed before the javascript is sent to the browser, your best bet is to include the javascript in your .aspx file (if you use webforms), where your html resides.